# how to send data from one collection with the data in another collection in nodejs express mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am new to nodejs .I want to send book data with stock details. When I call this function it only outputs empty array.

It sends store details before book details.  Can anyone help me with this?

i have schemas store and book.

Book Schema

```
module.exports = (mongoose) => {
  var schema = mongoose.Schema({
title : String,
author : String,
publishedYear : String,
barcode : String,
category : String

  });

  schema.method("toJSON", function () {
    const { __v, _id, ...object } = this.toObject();
    object.id = _id;
    return object;
  });

  const Book = mongoose.model("book", schema);
  return Book;
};
```

Store

```
module.exports = (mongoose) => {
  var schema = mongoose.Schema({
name : String,
address : String,
currentStock : String,


  });

  schema.method("toJSON", function () {
    const { __v, _id, ...object } = this.toObject();
    object.id = _id;
    return object;
  });

  const Store = mongoose.model("store", schema);
  return Store;
};
```

This is controller function

```
  exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
  Store.find()
    .then(data => {
      BookStore = []
data.forEach(store => {
 Book.findById(store.bookId).then((BookData) => {
          console.log(itemData)
          let storearray = {
            name: store.name,
          currentStock : store.currentStock 
            bookName: BookData
          }
          BookStore.push(storearray)
         
        }).catch((e) => { console.log(e) }).finally(() => {
          res.send(BookStore)
        })
 })
    })
 }
```

Comment: Why are you calling it tables? It's call collections in MongoDB. Also show us your schema so we can better understand the context better

Comment: ok thank you. i added schemas